# 'Bitcoin Core - Error'

Tags: bitcoin-core, error

I just tried downloading Bitcoin Core to my PC today for the first time and am getting an error. I am a noob to this, but was hoping someone could point me in the right direction in getting this fixed as I'm trying to get smarter on this stuff. Google led me to try re-indexing, but unfortunately that crashed as well after a few hours of running.

The below is the error message and the debug file. It appears it crashed due to a corrupt block found and potential hardware error. It could certainly be a hardware error as I only currently have the storage space for a full node on an old HDD, but haven't had any issues with this HDD previously.

Appreciate any help here. Thanks!

[image: error]

[image: debug log]

[image: HDD Stats]

**New Error When downloading on new SSD**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when a block that was written to disk is corrupted. This could be due to hardware failure or just simply random chance. Since the corrupted block for you occurred early on, the easiest way to fix this issue is to simply delete the blockchain and redownload it. To do that, just delete the `blocks/` and `chainstate/` folders inside of the datadir (the directory that contains the debug.log file). Then start Bitcoin Core.

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast response! Deleted and starting over. Thanks

Comment: So it appears to have crashed again with the first error in the debug log being the same as previously posted. Would the recommended next steps be the same in that I should just delete blocks/chainstate and try again, and then if this keeps happening to assume it's a HDD issue and I should buy a new SSD? Or any other recommendations to try first? It appears to have got through ~50gigs in the block folder this time.

Comment: You could try again, but since you have already hit the same error twice, I think it's safe to assume that your hard drive has gone bad. You probably want to run some diagnostics on it also. You don't necessarily need a SSD, just a drive that isn't failing.

Comment: Hmm, just posted a disk analysis in the OP and it says it's in good health but admittedly not a hdd expert so uncertain if any of the variables stand out as impacting this download specifically. Trying some drive optimizations and going to give it another shot. It's an old HDD but I've never had any issues previously.

Comment: So after giving it a few more tries, I kept getting the same error so bought a new SSD and just a few minutes into downloading it got an error as well. I'm going to try re-indexing, but curious if there are any other hardware errors that this could be or any other issues that come to mind? Appreciate all the help here.

Comment: I've now tried with my original HDD and two separate SSDs with the same errors. Is it possible this is being driven by an issue with my motherboard or some other piece of hardware. Struggling to determine the issue here. Thanks again.

Comment: @ctownballer03 It could be a memory error. You can try running a RAM diagnostic tool like memtest86.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help, it's truly appreciated. Looks like a RAM issue, memtest86 came back ~100 errors after running for 30 minutes.

Comment: thanks again for all the help, forgot to come back sooner but been running seamlessly for ~2 weeks after replacing the RAM.